# google-github-actions Not found; Gaia id not found for email ***

Tags: google-cloud-platform, github-actions

I am following this GitHub Action project (https://github.com/google-github-actions/deploy-cloudrun) and added the action "Build and Deploy to Cloud Run" to my GitHub project.

During the actions workflow, I get the following error message

```
Error: google-github-actions/auth failed with: retry function failed after 1 attempt: failed to generate Google Cloud access token for ***: (404) {
  "error": {
    "code": 404,
    "message": "Not found; Gaia id not found for email ***",
    "status": "NOT_FOUND"
  }
}
```

I created a new (from the scratch) GCP project and followed the instuctions on https://github.com/google-github-actions/auth#setting-up-workload-identity-federation to set up the federation, and it worked fine so far. But during the execution of the GitHub action, I got the error message.

Where can I set the Gaia id for the email?

Thank you in advance for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found my own mistake by not placing the secrets.WIF_SERVICE_ACCOUNT variable correctly. It hast to be "my-service-account@my-project-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com".

Comment: However, now I get the exception

```
denied: Permission "artifactregistry.repositories.uploadArtifacts" denied on resource "projects/myprojectid/locations/europe-west3/repositories/mycloudrun" (or it may not exist)

```
The difficulty here is, that next to the cloud run instance, I have to create a cloud build instance in order not to use a gcr. But here I think could be my mistake.